# jest / react-native: replacing/disbaling Linking.catch

Tags: react-native, jestjs

Having trouble testing the following react-native code.

What I would like to do is to replace Linking.openURL and Linking.OpenURL.catch with my mock code.

I am doing it for Linking.openURL as following:

```
jest.mock('Linking', () => {
      return {
        openURL: jest.fn()
      }
    })

Linking.openURL.mockImplementation(() => true)
```

But I keep getting:

```
TypeError: _reactNative.Linking.openURL(...).catch is not a function
```

Any idea how to replace/disable the catch clause?
This is my code:

```
func1() {

    switch (this.props.a) {
      case 'NO':
        this.alertMessage(`msg`)
        break
      case 'YES':
      default:
        Linking.openURL(url1).catch(err => { Linking.openURL(url2)
        })
    }
  }

  alertMessage = (title) => {
    Alert.alert(
      title,
      '',
      [
        { text: 'OK',
          onPress: () => {
            Linking.openURL(url1).catch(err => {
              Linking.openURL(url2)
            })
          } },
        { text: 'Cancel',
          onPress: () => {
            this.setState({
              stateVar1: true
            })
          },
          style: 'cancel' }
      ]
    )
  };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Linking.openURL` returns a `Promise`, so the mock function needs to return one as well. If you want to test what happens on `catch` you can `reject` the promise (or `resolve` it if you don't want the catch to be called).

Here's an example for the mock with the promise rejected:

```
jest.mock('Linking', () => ({
  openURL: jest.fn(() => Promise.reject('some error reason'))
}));
```

Comment: Thanks @Artal , I still get "TypeError: _reactNative.Linking.openURL(...).catch is not a function" for the line "Linking.openURL(url).catch(err => {"

Comment: That’s strange. When using your mock I got the same error, the promise solved it. Make sure that you don’t use both jest.mock and mockImplementation because it changes the previous mock

Comment: You are right. My fault... BTW, if I want to define both resolve and reject, any idea how I do that?

Comment: Option 1: create 2 describe sections (they can even be inside your parent describe section) and then you can mock it differently for each case. Option 2: use mockImplementation like you did (also modify it to return a promise), but do it first thing in the test code (right before calling the code that you’re testing), this way you can mock it differently each time. I think that the first solution is cleaner, but both are valid

Answer (score 9):

Just in case someone gets an error with the message `Cannot find module 'Linking' from`

Just replace `Linking` with `react-native/Libraries/Linking/Linking`.

So your code should look something like this:

```
jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/Linking/Linking', () => ({
  openURL: jest.fn(() => Promise.reject('some error reason'))
}));
```